# Understanding passing function as props in Tic Tac Toe example React

Tags: reactjs

In am a beginner in React. In the [Tic Tac Toe Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) on the official React website, there are 3 Components:

1. Square
2. Board (consisting of 3x3 Square Components)
3. Game (parent of Board)

The idea is that whenever a square Component is clicked the clicked event will pass up to the Board and further up to the Game Component. The Game Component will handle this onClick event.

```
 <Board onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}/>
```

`handleClick(i)` is a function inside Board Component.

**Board Component**

```
<Square onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}/>
```

**Square Component**

```
<button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}></button>
```

The above code snippet is from index.js at: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010)

What I could not understand is what does:

```
 <Board onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}/>
```

mean?

What does `i` mean here ? Where does it come from ? If we remove `i` then why does not the function work ?

Comment: I rather they wrote it as `e` for `event`, it is confusing as `i`.

Comment: @PFuster In fact as Board component has no native onClick handler, i don't think e is referring to an event. If you follow the call chain `i` is probably an integer referring to the square's index.

Comment: Oh my bad that is true. In this case it's their custom component prop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i => this.handleClick(i)` is an [arrow function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
It is quite similar as the `boundFunction` declaration below :

```
function myFunction(i) {
  this.handleClick(i);
}
const boundFunction = myFunction.bind(this);
```

`onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}` is the way to pass a property to a component. This allows you to access the function within the Board Component via `this.props.onClick` and to execute that function via `this.props.onClick(whatEverValueYouWant)`.

**Edit**

To see thing clearer, i am completing my answer with the call sequence there.

`button.onClick(event) => Square.props.onClick() => Board.props.onClick(i) => Game.handleClick(i)`

The click on the button triggers the `onClick` function defined on the button tag. This function is defined as `this.props.onClick`  wich refers to the Square property onClick defined on the Square tag like follows : `() => this.props.onClick(i)`, with `i` referring to the index of the Square.
So this function is called with the native event which is not used. The function could have beend defined like that `(event) => this.props.onClick(i)`. Since the event is not used there is no point declaring this attribute.

On the Square tag `this.props.onClick`refers to the Board property onClick defined like that: `(i) => this.handleClick(i)`. So one click on the button is triggering `handleClick` method defined in the Game component with an index i value defined somewhere in the Board component, probably within a loop rendering all the Squares.

Answer (score 3):

It's a parameter of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions are a simplified way of writing a function, where [parenthesis are **sometimes** optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax).

<s>The first parameter of the onClick property is usually the event itself. So it's just passing the event to `handleClick`.</s>

Comment: Looking at the function `handleClick` it is taking index `i` as parameter and not `event` since `i` is directly used to refer to an element of square array. Could you please explain how `index` of the square has been propagated from the Square child?

Comment: @bhavesh The only time the onClick is called with the event triggering it is on the button element. They could do stuff with the event like that  `<Square onClick={(event) => // do stuff with event }` or like that `<button onClick={(event) => // do stuff with event }`

Answer (score 0):

`i` is the return value of his children (the return value of the onClick event of Square).

Answer (score 0):

As in the code the Board component has a props of type function which is called when its div gets clicked

```
   onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
```

So on its parent the props is injected with a function that accept first parameter as the index of board. In this case they use an arrow function to define that function props.